# Writing while loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, while-loop, logic

How do you run a while loop if

```
a=10
```

and

```
b=100
```

and

```
c=.1,
```

where when 'a' and 'b' are more than 'c' apart, it will divide 'a' by 1.2 and 'b' by 2.2, so they change every time.
This is what i have so far. But I know its wrong....
Thanks!

```
a = 10;
b = 100;
c = .1;
while (b-a)>c
a = a/1.2;
b = b/2.2;
end
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want? How is your code incorrect?

Comment: I think something is wrong in this part  while (b-a)>c , b and a have to be more than c apart from each other, but I do not think this code correctly displays that

Comment: @user4999605 what about `abs(b-a)>c`

Comment: Have you run it? How are the results different from what you expect?

Comment: When I run with abs(b-a)>c the final values of a and b are a lot smaller, this actually makes sense since b is dividing faster than a, there will be a time where a and b are still c apart but b-a <c, which is why my original code isn't fool proof, thank you!